# How to deploy angular/springboot to azure?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, azure

I have an app that uses angular for the front end and spring boot/postgres for the back.  It all builds to a single jar file. It works fine locally but now I want to deploy it to Azure.  I have googled for hours on this topic but very little out there.  I can deploy front and back separately but can't find any info on how to connect them.  The closest thing I can find it this:
https://medium.com/@raviraj199602/azure-app-services-deploy-spring-boot-backend-in-azure-cloud-470f28b88864
But it fails to show how the front and back are connected. There must be a simple example somewhere since there are probably thousands of angular/spring apps deployed on azure.  Can someone point me to a good reference?

Comment: inside that "jar" file where you put the built Angular app?

Comment: There is a main folder.  Inside that folder is one for the spring boot back end, and one for the angular front end.  The pom file in the main folder has the other two as modules.  You build the main folder with maven and that creates a jar file in the backend folder.  Then I do java -jar appname.jar and it runs.  I open a web page to localhost:8080 and there it is.

Comment: this might help: https://www.kleemans.ch/deploy-a-spring-boot-amp-angular-app-to-azure

Comment: funny, I was just reading that one.  unfortunately it uses gradle instead of maven.  this project is really big, all controlled by maven.  I'll try to convert his tutorial to maven and then maybe I'll be able to figure it out.  thanks for the link

Comment: checkout this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx9SbQ1ANLk I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Create Angular App

1. Install Node.js [https://nodejs.org/en/download/]](https://nodejs.org/en/download/%5D) (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Open Command Prompt > Run `npm install -g @angular/cli`
3. Create Project **ng new AngularAAD**
4. Go inside folder & Run command **ng serve**
5. Browse the URL `http://localhost:4200`

Build the Angular App using command:
**ng build –prod**
Now you should get the  **dist**  folder which we need for deployment.

### Create Azure App Service

Go to Azure Portal > App Services > Create New > Choose the version depending on the Node Version.

Run command **node** to get the version

Choose OS > **Windows** > **Create** button.
In the Index Menu of App Service > Advanced Services (KUDU Console) of the App Service

[image]

Open Command Prompt > `wwwroot` folder.
Copy the **dist** folder contents to it.

[image]

### Test Deployment

From the main page, browse the App Service.